# how to give XML as input to XML webservice and receive XML as output

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I want to send XML file as input to XML Webservice and receive output as XML.

Following code is my first attempted:

```
XmlDocument node = new XmlDocument();
node.LoadXml("<IDV>" +
    "<start_date>" + "25/12/2014" + "</start_date>"<br>
    "<vehicle_class_cd>" + "45" + "</vehicle_class_cd>"
    "<RTOLocation>" + "10416" + "</RTOLocation>"
    "<vehiclemodelcode>" + "22647" + "</vehiclemodelcode>"
    "<manufacturer_code>" + "12474" + "</manufacturer_code>"
    "<purchaseregndate>" + "27" + "</purchaseregndate>"
    "<manufacturingyear>" + "2014" + "</manufacturingyear>"       
    "</IDV>");

demo.Service src = new demo.Service();
var str = src.getIDV(node.ToString());
```

Comment: You will most likely get more help if you post the code of your service (the `getIDV` method) and what the current behavior is.  As it stands right now you really don't have much of a question, as you haven't described the problem you're facing (i.e., do you get errors, does it not work, etc).

Comment: Also, there's no need to create an `XmlDocument` since you're converting it to a `string` when you pass it to the service - just create the string.

Comment: thax tim , for the reply

Comment: I dont have the code of webservice as i am using the webservice provided by other , which require the input as XML ,in above format .. I am providing the input in the same format as required by i m not getting any output or error...

Comment: Have you contacted the owner of the service you are using?  They're probably best positioned to help you.